# Broadcast receiver before app update

Tags: android

Is there a broadcast that android sends before starting the app update ? Android currently sends a broadcast `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` (and other variants) after the app is updated. But I wanted my app to know when it is going to be updated.